# Numpy/pandas modules not recognized on Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-lab, python-module

I am running Python in Jupyter Lab and am getting the "no module named ___" error. This is occurring for several common modules (numpy, pandas, etc) that are downloaded and appear when I use the *conda list* command in the terminal. My PC and Jupyter Lab were running different versions of python, so I downloaded Python 3.8.10 in the terminal so that it matched Jupyter Lab.

I tried installing numpy in my script before trying to import numpy, but it still won't work.

`!pip install numpy`

`Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/shh/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.23.5)`

`import numpy as np`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

The odd thing is that my .ipynb files were running just fine a couple days ago and then this error randomly popped up.

Comment: " My PC and Jupyter Lab were running different versions of python, so I downloaded Python 3.8.10 in the terminal so that it matched Jupyter Lab." what exactly does that mean? It sounds like you may have several different interpreters. Whatever `pip` is associated with is not the interpreter being used as the kernel for your jupyter session